# How to store decimal values in DB?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

Not getting decimal point values while adding to db. It's automatically rounded to nearest digit.

I have declared it as

```
 public Decimal Amt { get; set; }
```

and in my main model it is as

```
public int Add(Decimal Amt)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ledger(Amt)VALUES(@AMT)";                    
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMT", Amt);
                    int modified = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
                    return modified;
                }
            }
        }
```

and in DB it's datatype is Decimal(18,0).

Answer (score 5):

Decimal(18,0) means 0 digits stored to the right of the decimal point.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Second Parameter in Decimal(18,0) is 0 that means that you don't want decimal place. For Example if u define Decimal(18,2), it will give till 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

change the datatype to (18,6) or so, whichever is suitable for you,

The second part of decimal data type shows how many digits do you require after the 'point'. In your case it's '0', so db is rounding it to nearest integer.